Next.js with Material UI: How to Disable Accordion but Keep Default Styling?
I'm working on a Next.js project and using Material UI for the UI components. I have an Accordion component that I need to disable under certain conditions but still display without the disabled styling (greyed out look).
Here is my ShowLyrics component:
function ShowLyrics({ song }: Readonly<{ song: song }>) {
    return (
        <Accordion
            disabled={!song?.lyrics}
        >
            <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={song?.lyrics ? <MdLyrics className='text-black' /> : null}
            >
                {song.name}
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                {song?.lyrics ? song.lyrics : 'Paroles non disponibles'}
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    );
}

I've tried various methods to achieve this, including using the class, classes, className, sx, and tw props. I also attempted to move the disabled prop to the AccordionDetails, which resulted in the background color changing back to normal, but the text remained grey, and I couldn't override it.
Additionally, I tried using createTheme from Material UI, but it didn't work as expected. Here is the code I used:
createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiAccordion: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    '&.Mui-disabled': {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
                        textColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

Any advice on how to disable the Accordion while keeping the default styling would be greatly appreciated!

You need to handle both onChange event to disable change and add custom sx for keeping cursor: default like this:
<Accordion
    expanded={expanded2}
    onChange={() => null /*do nothing*/}
>
    <AccordionSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
      id="panel2bh-header"
      sx={{ cursor: 'default!important' }}
    >
      <Typography sx={{ width: '90%', flexShrink: 0 }}>
        Disabled but Default Styled
      </Typography>
    </AccordionSummary>
    <AccordionDetails>
      <Typography>
        Donec placerat, lectus sed mattis semper, neque lectus feugiat
        lectus, varius pulvinar diam eros in elit. Pellentesque convallis
        laoreet laoreet.
      </Typography>
    </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.

Thank you. In addition to the onChange, the expanded prop had to be a useState as in your example.

You're right, the component should be controlled component.
